# Comparing regressions - multiple DVs

Tags: regression, interaction, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I don't have a lot of experience with stats besides basic t-tests and ANOVAs and have just started using R, so please bare with me if my questions seem simplistic.  I have a 3 part question, I hope that is allowed here?  If not, please let me know and I'll separate the questions.

First the context:
For my dataset I have performed a repeated-measures test.  I'm looking at the regressions between my independent variable (x: mass) and my dependent variable (y).  I have tested y in 3 separate conditions (A, B, C).

My questions:

1. For each condition I need to be able to identify whether a simple linear (y=ax + c) or simple power (y=ax^b) regression is more appropriate. Previously this is not obvious visually due to the mass-range tested.

   - From my reading I believe that the assumptions are the best way to show this? Seeing as though r2 cannot be used with a non-linear regression.  Is this correct?
   - Alternatively, can I use an AIC or BIC comparison?
   - Or, do you know of a better approach?
2. Assuming the regressions are linear, I need to show whether there is a significant difference in the regression slopes between the conditions (A, B, C). Would you suggest an ANOVA with post-hoc test for interactions to do this?
3. I need to do the same as Q2. but assuming that the regressions are in the power format (my main focus here is on the exponent value).  Can I still use the ANOVA for non-linear regressions?